# Tableau: stacked side-by-side bars with two different dimensions splitting the columns

Tags: tableau-api, stacked-chart

I am trying to create a stacked side-by-side bar chart over time with 2 measures:

- Total Calls (Split by type of a call)
- Requests (Split by type of a request)

I have reached a point where I can get this view:
[image: Current chart]

I am struggling with getting 'Calls' bar colored by the call type, and Requests by the its own type, to ultimately receive this:

[image: expected outcome]

(purple colors: types of calls, red-orange-blue colors: types of requests.

Comment: Try putting the `Measure Names` pill into the chart instead of the individual measures.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use a Dual Axis. Instead, put [Measure Values] on the shelf and filter your measures to  Requests and Calls.  This should create the stacked side by side effect you're going for.

If you're data is structured in a tidy format such that each row level record is either a call or request, then to get the colors right, you can create a calculated field that uses the appropriate dimension for color based up on whether the record is a call or request.  E.g.

```
If ISNULL([Call]) THEN [Request Type] ELSE [Call Type]
```

If your request and call measure are contained in the same row level record, that you will have to use use a combined dimension, with both dimensions on the color shelf.